# Python - CSV read as one big line

Tags: python, csv, readlines

I'm new to Python and I'm learning from a tutorial, and there is this line here that is suppose to read from a .csv file and skip the first line (header):

```
data = open("banklist.csv", "r").readlines()[1:]
for entry in data:
  #do some stuffs
```

Problem is, it is not even entering the loop. Removing the [1:] in the open statement and adding print data, I find that the csv seems to be read as one big line, and removing the header removed everything instead:

```
["First National Bank also operating as The National Bank of El Paso,Edinburg,TX,14318,13-Sep-13,18-Sep-13\rThe Community's Bank,Bridgeport,CT,57041,13-Sep-13,17-Sep-13\rSunrise Bank of Arizona,Phoenix,AZ,34707,23-Aug-13,11-Sep-13\rCommunity South Bank,Parsons,TN,19849,23-Aug-13,5-Sep-13\rBank of Wausau,Wausau,WI,35016,9-Aug-13,4-Sep-13\rFirst Community Bank of Southwest Florida (also operating as Community Bank of Cape Coral),Fort Myers,FL,34943,2-Aug-13,26-Aug-13\rMountain National Bank,Sevierville,TN,34789,7-Jun-13,26-Aug-13\r1st Commerce Bank,North Las Vegas,NV,58358,6-Jun-13,26-Aug-13\rBanks of Wisconsin d/b/a Bank of Kenosha,Kenosha,WI,35386,31-May-13,12-Jul-13\rCentral Arizona Bank,Scottsdale,AZ,34527,14-May-13,26-Aug-13\rSunrise Bank,Valdosta,GA,58185,10-May-13,12-Jul-13\rPisgah Community Bank,Asheville,NC,58701,10-May-13,26-Aug-13\rDouglas County Bank,Douglasville,GA,21649,26-Apr-13,26-Aug-13\rParkway Bank,Lenoir,NC,57158,26-Apr-13,26-Aug-13\rChipola Community Bank,Marianna,FL,58034,19-Apr-13,12-Jul-13\rHeritage Bank of North Florida,Orange Park,FL,26680,19-Apr-13,26-Aug-13\rFirst Federal Bank,Lexington,KY,29594,19-Apr-13,12-Jul-13"]
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: Python has a csv parser module

Comment: I could use that module, but any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe a mismatch of newline escape sequences?

Comment: The carriage returns `\r` are not being handled correctly hence the error, use the `csv` module

Comment: Is this a file that has come from a different operating system, e.g. from MAC OS to Windows?

Comment: You could just split on `\r` like so `lines = data.split('\r')` will produce a list of the lines

Comment: I could use, no, you should use it. You are trying to be smarter than the csv module and trying to reinvent the wheel, but you are not.

Comment: @EdChum: The CSV module doesn't automatically handle `\r` *either*, only opening the file in universal newline mode does. That or use `str.splitlines()` to split an existing string on any of the three newline conventions.

Comment: I must say I don't quite see why this question was downvoted; the OP showed what he tried, what output was expected, what he got instead. The naive comment of 'use the `csv` module' doesn't actually solve the problem either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the info, I think this post like many others is a victim of drive-by down voting, I prefer giving feedback and commenting to educate OP rather than `death by 5 close votes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a text file that uses a different newline convention from your system; `\r` where probably your system expects either `\n` or `\r\n`.

You can open the file using universal newline support instead with the `'rU'` mode:

```
data = open("banklist.csv", "rU").readlines()[1:]
```

The smarter way to skip that first line is to use the file as an iterator; loop over it directly. The `next()` method lets you grab one line at a time, giving you a method to skip the first line:

```
with open("banklist.csv", "rU") as infile:
    next(infile, None)  # skip the first line
    for line in infile:
        print line
```

However, if this a CSV file, use the `csv` module to read the data:

```
import csv

with open("banklist.csv", "rU") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    next(reader, None)  # skip the first row
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

The CSV module handles splitting the lines into lists for you:

```
['First National Bank also operating as The National Bank of El Paso', 'Edinburg', 'TX', '14318', '13-Sep-13', '18-Sep-13']
["The Community's Bank", 'Bridgeport', 'CT', '57041', '13-Sep-13', '17-Sep-13']
['Sunrise Bank of Arizona', 'Phoenix', 'AZ', '34707', '23-Aug-13', '11-Sep-13']
['Community South Bank', 'Parsons', 'TN', '19849', '23-Aug-13', '5-Sep-13']
['Bank of Wausau', 'Wausau', 'WI', '35016', '9-Aug-13', '4-Sep-13']
['First Community Bank of Southwest Florida (also operating as Community Bank of Cape Coral)', 'Fort Myers', 'FL', '34943', '2-Aug-13', '26-Aug-13']
# etc.
```

Comment: Thanks! That \r looked really suspicious.